# Partition graph's edges into $k+1$ pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a (simple) graph with maximum degree $k \gt 1$ and exactly $k(k + 1)$
edges. Prove that the set of edges of $G$ can be partitioned into $k + 1$ pairwise disjoint sets, each forming a matching of size precisely $k$.

Completely lost with this one. Yhere is a hint but I just have no idea.

Hint: Apply Vizing's theorem and then show that for any two edge-disjoint matchings $M_1$ and $M_2$ with $|M_2| \ge |M_1| + 2$ there are edge-disjoint matchings $M'_1, M'_2$ with $M'_1 \cup M'_
2 = M_1 \cup M_2$ and $|M'_1| = |M1| + 1$.

Comment: Vizing's theorem says that $G$ is $(k+1)$-edge-colorable, right? So the edges can be partitioned into $k+1$ pairwise disjoint sets, each forming a matching; however, the sizes of those matchings may vary. At least we know, since the number of edges in $G$ is $k(k+1)$, the **average** size of those $k+1$ matchings is $k$; we need somehow to even them up. The last part of the hint  tells us how to do that by swapping edges between matchings. To prove that statement note that the graph $(V,M_1\cup M_2)$ has maximum degree $\le2$, so each component is a cycle (of even length--why?) or a path.

Comment: okay i think i got it
thank you @bof